# Cakephp multilevel assosication not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp, associations

**What I tried:**

My First model

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Appregister extends AppModel {

    public $name        = 'Appregister';
    public $useTable    = 'app_register';


    public $primaryKey  = 'id';

    var $hasOne = array(        
        'Pollusers' => array(
            'className' => 'Pollusers',
            'foreignKey' => 'AppRegisterId',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

Second:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Pollusers extends AppModel {

    public $name        = 'Pollusers';
    public $useTable    = 'poll_users';


    public $primaryKey  = 'id';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Pollresult' => array(
            'className' => 'Pollresult',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Third:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * CakePHP Pollresult
 * @author Kalpesh
 */
class Pollresult extends AppModel {
    public $name        = 'Pollresult';
    public $useTable    = 'poll_result';


    public $primaryKey  = 'id';


}
```

now I have set 
**`$this->Appregister->recursive = 2;`**

Still it gives me error like:

```
 Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Pollresult.poll_id' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `Appregister`.`device_token`, `Appregister`.`type` FROM
`reviewpr_aljassem`.`app_register` AS `Appregister` 
LEFT JOIN `reviewpr_aljassem`.`poll_users` AS `Pollusers` 
       ON (`Pollusers`.`AppRegisterId` = `Appregister`.`id`) 
WHERE 1=1 And 
     `Pollresult`.`poll_id` = 11 And 
     `Pollresult`.`answer_id` = "1" AND 
      `Appregister`.`type` != 3
```

So whats wrong here, why its not joining Pollresult in query?

**Updated**

here 
**`Appregister ----hasone---> Pollusers ----hasmany---> Pollresult`**

so i checked and got to know that how cakephp handles hasmany relation:

```
[4] => Array
                (
                    [query] => SELECT `Appregister`.`id`, `Appregister`.`app_id`, `Appregister`.`vendor_id`, `Appregister`.`device_token`, `Appregister`.`type`, `Appregister`.`created_date`, `Appregister`.`modified_date`, `Pollusers`.`id`, `Pollusers`.`AppRegisterId`, `Pollusers`.`age`, `Pollusers`.`gender`, `Pollusers`.`area_id`, `Pollusers`.`governor_ate`, `Pollusers`.`email`, `Pollusers`.`name`, `Pollusers`.`name_en`, `Pollusers`.`date` FROM `reviewpr_aljassem`.`app_register` AS `Appregister` LEFT JOIN `reviewpr_aljassem`.`poll_users` AS `Pollusers` ON (`Pollusers`.`AppRegisterId` = `Appregister`.`id`)  WHERE 1 = 1
                    [params] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [affected] => 96
                    [numRows] => 96
                    [took] => 2
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [query] => SELECT `Pollresult`.`id`, `Pollresult`.`poll_id`, `Pollresult`.`user_id`, `Pollresult`.`answer_id`, `Pollresult`.`date` FROM `reviewpr_aljassem`.`poll_result` AS `Pollresult`   WHERE `Pollresult`.`user_id` = (1)
                    [params] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [affected] => 1
                    [numRows] => 1
                    [took] => 0
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [query] => SELECT `Pollresult`.`id`, `Pollresult`.`poll_id`, `Pollresult`.`user_id`, `Pollresult`.`answer_id`, `Pollresult`.`date` FROM `reviewpr_aljassem`.`poll_result` AS `Pollresult`   WHERE `Pollresult`.`user_id` = (10)
                    [params] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [affected] => 1
                    [numRows] => 1
                    [took] => 0
                )
```

**gets the pollresult data in separate query so now how to join it in same query?**

Comment: Why don't you stick to cakephp naming convention? Your models should be singular, CamelCased words. From docs: _Foreign keys in hasMany, belongsTo or hasOne relationships are recognized by default as the (singular) name of the related table followed by _id_. You are doing to many things the wrong way here, have you even went through the docs?

Comment: @skywalker yeah i know that but I have not developed this project from scratch, so at this stage I can not change database

Comment: So there is a key named `AppRegisterId` in the database? Well models can be named correctly then.

Comment: yes AppRegisterId exists in polluser table

Comment: Have you tried adding containable behavior to you models? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html